# Iterating though a 2D list and put the elements in a Hashtable

Tags: java, list, hashtable, closest-points

I have a list of point coordinate and want to iterate through a 2D list then process the elements in the hash function to generate the key for my hashtable.
I am a bit struggling to iterate through the List> points, also how to pass coordinate (x,y) as value for to the hashtable (key,value)?

```
public static List<List<Integer>> myMethod(int k, List<List<Integer>> points){

    Hashtable  pt = new Hashtable();

    for (int i = 0; i <points.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < points.get(i).size(); j++)
        {
            Integer x = points.get(i);
            Integer y = points.get(j);
            pt.put(hashfunction( x, y), points.get(i));
        } 
    }

    //return list of pairs ;
}
```

Comment: What elements do you exactly want to store in your `Hashtable`? It looks like you are trying to store an `Integer` as key and a `List<Integer>` as value. Is that correct?

Comment: `Integer x = points.get(i);` will give you a list not `Integer` object

Comment: @TheScientificMethod correct, edited comment

Comment: I want to store key which is the distance to the origin for every pair of coordinate from the points list.

Comment: I am solving find k closest elements from a given list of points, so the key would be the distance calculated and value is the pair of coordinate (x,y).

Comment: The last step would be to put distances in an array, then sort it and pull k smallest distances,

Comment: Then I recommend not to use `List<Integer>` to only store 2 values (x and y) in it, Implement a class `Pair` that holds the two values. You can then store it in a `Map<Integer, Pair>` (in case the distance is of type `Integer` or `int`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to help yourself by using some data structures that more accurately reflect your data.  If you have point-data, consider using `Pair`, then your `List` of points is actually that!

Next, all the `Map` structures within `Java` will calculate their own hash values, you don't need to do that!  You will need to calculate your desired keys though.  From your snippet, it isn't clear why you want the `Hashtable/Map` at all - it is a local variable that is never read and will garbage collected right after the method executes.  Thus, I guessed that you wanted to return that.  If so you can do:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

public class TwoDimArray {

    public static Integer keyCalculator(Pair<Integer, Integer> point) {
        return point.getLeft() * point.getRight();
    }

     public static Map<Integer, Integer> myMethod(List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> points) {
        return points.stream()
                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> keyCalculator(p), p -> p.getRight()));

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pair<Integer, Integer> pointA = Pair.of(1, 2);
        Pair<Integer, Integer> pointB = Pair.of(3, 4);
        Pair<Integer, Integer> pointC = Pair.of(5, 6);
        List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> points = Lists.newArrayList(pointA, pointB, pointC);
        System.out.println("Points map: " + myMethod(points));

    }

}
```

Which outputs:

```
Points map: {2=2, 12=4, 30=6}
```

Comment: A `java.awt.Point` would probably fit even better here (and not have a dependency to some large Apache + Google libs...)

Comment: I am restricted to use this method signature with the specified List<List<Integer>> return type.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i <points.size(); i++) {
        List<Integer> in = points.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < in.size() - 1; j++) {
            Integer x = in.get(j);
            Integer y = in.get(j + 1);
            pt.put(hashfunction(x, y), points.get(i));
        } 
}
```